# Symfony2 JMSSecurityBundle @secure pass object obtained with @ParamConverter

Tags: symfony, annotations, symfony-2.3

Is possible pass a object obtained with paramconvert in @secure annotation ?

This is my code:

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("construction", class="CliConsCoreBundle:Construction", options={"repository_method" = "findWithJoins"})
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_EXTRANET", options={"construction"})
 * @Template
 */
public function showAction(Request $request, Construction $construction)
{ ... }
```

I want have $construction in security voter, is possible?

If I do without annotations then works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [@Secure](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/blob/master/Annotation/Secure.php) annotation receives an array of strings that represents the roles that the active user has to have for the controller to be executed.

What do you exactly want to do? I can't understand the intention of your code

Comment: Yes, but secure call the security voter and then I want comprove if this user can visit this construction I need the object in voter